# sort command understanding the logical sequence

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, opensuse, sort

sort -k 2 filename.txt means that it sorts by the second key but what would this following command mean: sort -k 3.3,3.5 for this data:
For example: I got this-->

```
Man in     Winter     England        1980.12.02                   
Richrd     Fritz      Scottland      1960.12.18
Max        Winter     GB             1955.12.09
Luther     Arnold     England        1990.05.12
Sebastian  Kalle      USA            1980.12.14
```

How can I get the solution for that list with this command:
sort -k 3.3,3.5 data.txt?

And how can you sort it by when you have 2 decimal numbers in general?

Comment: `sort -k3.3,3.5` is explained in the manual... the rest of your post doesn't make much sense...

Comment: Does your input contain tabs or spaces? Is the character between "Man" and "in" a space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume there are no tabs in the input. The interpretation of the command is pretty tricky:

```
sort -k3.3,3.5
```

means "sort by a substring from the third field from the third to the fifth character", but the counting begins at the first whitespace before the field, as mentioned in `man sort`:

> KEYDEF  is  F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]]  for  start  and stop position, where F is a
>          field number and C a character position in the field; both are origin 1,  and  the
>          stop  position  defaults  to  the  line's end.  If neither -t nor -b is in effect,
>          characters in a field are counted from the beginning of the preceding  whitespace.

Run the sort under LC_ALL=C to avoid locale influencing he sort order.

Note how the order changes if you add one more character, i.e.

```
LC_ALL=C sort -k3.3,3.6
```

Here's a short Perl script that shows what part of the input is used for sorting:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my $field_index = 3;
my $start       = 3;
my $stop        = 5; # Change to 6 to explain the different order.

while (my $line = <>) {
    chomp $line;
    my @fields = $line =~ /(\s*\S*)/g;

    my $length_before = 0;
    $length_before += length $fields[$_] for 0 .. $field_index - 2;

    my $from = $start - 1 + $length_before;
    my $to   = $stop + $length_before;
    $_ > length $line and $_ = length $line for $from, $to;

    substr $line, $to, 0, '>>';
    substr $line, $from, 0, '<<';

    say $line;
}
```

Output for 3.3,3.5:

```
Luther     Arnold  <<   >>England        1990.05.12
Man in  <<   >>Winter     England        1980.12.02                   
Max        Winter  <<   >>GB             1955.12.09
Richrd     Fritz  <<   >> Scottland      1960.12.18
Sebastian  Kalle  <<   >> USA            1980.12.14
```

Output for 3.3,3.6:

```
Richrd     Fritz  <<    >>Scottland      1960.12.18
Sebastian  Kalle  <<    >>USA            1980.12.14
Luther     Arnold  <<   E>>ngland        1990.05.12
Max        Winter  <<   G>>B             1955.12.09
Man in  <<   W>>inter     England        1980.12.02
```

Comment: something I've found useful (since the Q is tagged Linux, they probably have GNU sort) is the `sort --debug` option. Takes a little getting used to, but it shows what fields are being used for the sort as it goes along.

Comment: @JeffSchaller: Oh yes, that's what I wasted time simultating!